# product display with break column - woocommerce

Tags: css, woocommerce

[www.quickgamestore.ml](http://www.quickgamestore.ml)

My shop page is displaying the products well, but if my title is bigger than image witdh, the title comes along and break the column witdh as you can see below.

I'm looking for a css to fix (fixed with) my columns and don't break my layout. Anybody could help me?

**Above, the CSS I'm using to display the products and wrap the rows.**

```
.products { /*****styling products*****/
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  list-style: none;
  margin-right: 0.5rem;

}

.woocommerce ul.products li.product, .woocommerce-page ul.products li.product {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 20%;
  display: flex; 
}
```

[image]

Comment: You need to improve your question. It's impossible to know what you're trying to achieve with the information you've provided.

Comment: I edit my question. Tks man. But what I wnat is to display and style my products properlly. My title doesn't respect the column witdh, and if I use width: 20%, the flex-box won't work and the products are displayed one per row.

Comment: Can you please share a demo or the live URL?

Comment: www.quickgamestore.ml

Comment: live url still using list-item.